# OpenCV - How to match multi-instance of templates in image using C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, feature-extraction, feature-detection

I need some help trying to match non-normal blood cell with original cell. 
After some searches I found SURF and SIFT feature extraction.

I have this template;

[image: 1]

and this original image;

[image: 2]

This is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

Mat img_scene = imread("d:\\projimg\\last.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat img_object = imread("d:\\projimg\\lasttmp.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
//Mat img_object = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
//Mat img_scene = imread(argv[2], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

if (!img_object.data || !img_scene.data)
{
    std::cout << " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl; return -1;
}

//-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
int minHessian = 200;

SurfFeatureDetector detector(minHessian);

std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_object, keypoints_scene;

detector.detect(img_object, keypoints_object);
detector.detect(img_scene, keypoints_scene);

//-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;

Mat descriptors_object, descriptors_scene;

extractor.compute(img_object, keypoints_object, descriptors_object);
extractor.compute(img_scene, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene);

//-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
std::vector< DMatch > matches;
matcher.match(descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches);
matches.resize(10);
sort(matches.begin(), matches.end());
double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

//-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
for (int i = 0; i <matches.size(); i++)
{
    double dist = matches[i].distance;
    if (dist < min_dist) min_dist = dist;
    if (dist > max_dist) max_dist = dist;
}

printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist);
printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist);

//-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )
std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++)
{
    if (matches[i].distance < 3 * min_dist)
    {
        good_matches.push_back(matches[i]);
    }
}

Mat img_matches;
drawMatches(img_object, keypoints_object, img_scene, keypoints_scene,
    good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
    vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);

//-- Localize the object
std::vector<Point2f> obj;
std::vector<Point2f> scene;

for (int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++)
{
    //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
    obj.push_back(keypoints_object[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
    scene.push_back(keypoints_scene[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
}
imshow("ii", img_matches);
waitKey();
return 0;
}
```

Can  anyone help me to match all similar templates ?

Thanks all

Comment: not answer, but maybe you can try find all **normal** blood cell? (and the remained is not normal)

Comment: I don't think feature extractors will help you. I would try filtering them based on shape. Read the docs for [SimpleBlobDetector](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#simpleblobdetector)

Comment: do you have implemented code for normal blood cell or any idea how to do it ?

Comment: Try resizing the image template and perform correlation over the source image.